# Go: json.Unmarshal will transform []byte into string when unmarshalling in interface{}

Tags: json, go, encoding-json-go

In go, when I use json.Marshal on []byte & then json.Unmarshal inside a []byte I will get the same []byte that I used in input.

But when I json.Unmarshal inside an interface{} I will get a string.

Example here: https://goplay.tools/snippet/5BfFZ-Uq507

I've read json.Unmarshal documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) & this issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16815.

I understand that []byte and string are not the same type and that it's logical to have a different result then string([]byte("BOOKS")) if I tried to json.Unmarshal inside a string.

But since I unmarshaled into interface{}, I expected the type to be []byte and to have my original []byte back not a string.

This is a problem for me because I can't make a difference, when unmarshalling data into map[string]interface{}, between what was originally a string or a []byte.

Example: https://goplay.tools/snippet/MVSR7_MvSv-

Is there any way to solve my issue ?

Comment: There is no solution to your "problem" as there is no difference between "Book" and "Book" in JSON that could determine that _you_ want one to be a string and the other to be a []byte.

Comment: What is a string other than a byte slice (ignoring pedantic comments about multi-byte characters)? What syntactic/format options does JSON offer to allow you to distinguish between `[]byte` as being a slice of, effectively, `int8` values as opposed to a string? A byte slice will _have_ to be encoded as a string, so as to not have someone unmarshal an actual `[]int8{}` as a string. That's why your marshalled output shows the byte slice to be a string, and it's unmarshalled as such, except for when you explicitly unmarshal to a variable of type `[]byte`

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason, it is better to Unmarshal to a specific type in Go. It is also more secure as wrong types will just fail instead of being unmarshaled to a different type which the code might not deal with correctly (and thereby potentially expose a security vulnerability).

Comment: For the record, I 100% agree on the fact that Unmarshal to a specific type is better, it's actually what I'm doing, but some fields in my struct are interface{} because I can't know in advance what they will be... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially left a comment because this seemed like a trivial issue, although the questions you're asking and things you mention suggest that there's actually a fair few things to unpack.

1. You want a `[]byte` not a string.

What are these types, let's start with that. As per [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions), the `byte` type is an alias for `uint8`

A string is effectively a sequence of bytes, so therefore a string is a sequence of `uint8` values. It is its own type, but let's take a closer look:

> A string type represents the set of string values. A string value is a (possibly empty) sequence of bytes. The number of bytes is called the length of the string and is never negative. Strings are immutable: once created, it is impossible to change the contents of a string. The predeclared string type is string; it is a defined type.

With this in mind, you can see that a string can be copied and cast safely to a `[]byte`, but the main difference here is that a `string` is immutable, whereas a `[]byte` is not:

```
s := "this is an immutable string"
cpy := []byte(s)
cpy[0] = 'T'
s2 := string(cpy)
fmt.Printf("%s != %s\n", s, s2)
```

This is all to say that, for the purposes of marshalling something, the input is immutable, and therefore there is no difference between `[]byte` and `string`.

Cool, but didn't I just say that `[]byte` is an alias for `[]uint8`. Correct, so at this point you'd still expect `[]byte` to be encoded as `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`. So let's take a look at the source code of the `encoding/json` package, in particular [this line](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/encoding/json/encode.go;l=826) stands out

```
func newSliceEncoder(t reflect.Type) encoderFunc {
    // Byte slices get special treatment; arrays don't.
    if t.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Uint8 {
        p := reflect.PointerTo(t.Elem())
        if !p.Implements(marshalerType) && !p.Implements(textMarshalerType) {
            return encodeByteSlice
        }
    }
    enc := sliceEncoder{newArrayEncoder(t)}
    return enc.encode
}
```

Notice the comment: **Byte slices get special treatment**, which returns `encodeByteSlice` as an `encoderFunc`. Clearly, we are returning a different encoder callback when dealing with a slice of bytes, so let's look at what that encoder function looks like...

```
func encodeByteSlice(e *encodeState, v reflect.Value, _ encOpts) {
    if v.IsNil() {
        e.WriteString("null")
        return
    }
    s := v.Bytes()
    encodedLen := base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(s))
    e.Grow(len(`"`) + encodedLen + len(`"`))

    // TODO(https://go.dev/issue/53693): Use base64.Encoding.AppendEncode.
    b := e.AvailableBuffer()
    b = append(b, '"')
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b[len(b):][:encodedLen], s)
    b = b[:len(b)+encodedLen]
    b = append(b, '"')
    e.Write(b)
}
```

And there we have it: a byte slice is handled specifically to write the values to the buffer delimited by `"`, meaning the values will be encoded as a JSON string. Just like that, we can perfectly explain the behaviour you've observed:

1. You've cast a string to a `[]byte`, which is valid
2. You've marshalled the resulting byte slice
3. In marshalling, you've hit the point where a byte slice (or `[]uint8`) is treated as a special case
4. The data is encoded as a JSON string

Now when it comes to unmarshalling, what's going on with your `var dataAny any` case? Well, let's look at the source code for the unmarshalling, specifically [this part](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.6:src/encoding/json/decode.go;l=931)

```
case '"': // string
    s, ok := unquoteBytes(item)
    if !ok {
        if fromQuoted {
            return fmt.Errorf("json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal %q into %v", item, v.Type())
        }
        panic(phasePanicMsg)
    }
    switch v.Kind() {
    default:
        d.saveError(&UnmarshalTypeError{Value: "string", Type: v.Type(), Offset: int64(d.readIndex())})
    case reflect.Slice:
        if v.Type().Elem().Kind() != reflect.Uint8 {
            d.saveError(&UnmarshalTypeError{Value: "string", Type: v.Type(), Offset: int64(d.readIndex())})
            break
        }
        b := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.DecodedLen(len(s)))
        n, err := base64.StdEncoding.Decode(b, s)
        if err != nil {
            d.saveError(err)
            break
        }
        v.SetBytes(b[:n])
    case reflect.String:
        if v.Type() == numberType && !isValidNumber(string(s)) {
            return fmt.Errorf("json: invalid number literal, trying to unmarshal %q into Number", item)
        }
        v.SetString(string(s))
    case reflect.Interface:
        if v.NumMethod() == 0 {
            v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(string(s)))
        } else {
            d.saveError(&UnmarshalTypeError{Value: "string", Type: v.Type(), Offset: int64(d.readIndex())})
        }
    }
```

This covers both of your unmarshal cases quite nicely. The JSON encoded input starts with a `"`, so we enter the case that deals with unmarshalling strings. We get the data from the input minus the quotes as a slice of bytes (`unquotedBytes()`). Next, we check what type the destination (`v`) for the unmarshalled data is. We accept 3 types:

1. A slice type, but if it's anything other than a slice of `uint8`, we return an error (meaning we only really accept `[]byte`)
2. A string type - because of course we're unmarshalling a string
3. An `any`, or interface type

If the destination is of type `any`, we do a quick check to make sure that the underlying type truly is an empty interface (ie we're not trying to write data to something other than a literal empty interface), and if so, we call

```
v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(string(s)))
```

We explicitly set its value to a string, because we are unmarshalling a string.

When the destination is a `[]byte`, we end up using `v.SetBytes(b[:n])`, so we copy the values over to a byte slice. Simple as can be.

---

Now what you're actually looking for is a way to ensure that what is marshalled as a `[]byte` is unmarshalled as a `[]byte`. From the code above, it should be fairly obvious by now that this can't be done. you can *force* something like this by converting your `[]byte` to an `[]int`:

```
s := "foobar"
si := make([]int, 0, len(s))
for _, c := range []byte(s) {
    si = append(si, int(c))
}
```

But that makes the marshalled data very silly. It's only really useful if both parties involved in the data-exchange know what to do with slices/arrays of numbers, **and** there are no cases where you actually want to send a slice of numeric values that shouldn't be interpreted as a string

This all leads in to the last point of note: you mentioned marshalling the data into a `map[string]any`. This makes me think we're dealing with an X-Y problem here.

Sometimes, you're needing to unmarshal data which you can't know the type of (usually data you need to pass on to some other process that will be able to identify what the data means, and how to process it). In those (rare) cases, using a `map[string]any` can be a useful validation step to make sure you're not sending malformed payloads to that other process.

However your trying to force a string to be represented as a `[]byte` suggests you're very much aware of what data you're dealing with, how it ought to be represented, what it means, and which fields need to be handled in this particular way. If that is the case: why bother with the whole `map[string]any` mess? For that to work/be used, you'll have to litter your code with hard-coded keys for the map to extract the bits of data you need. Just create a type, that implements the JSONMarshal and JSONUnmarshal methods, and you can handle specific fields in specific ways. You could, even though I'm still finding it impossible to think of a valid reason for it, convert strings to int slices and back again in the marshalling process

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It's very interesting and helped me understand what was going on ! I love that you added the go source code to explain !

My problem is very peculiar and I'm sure I can find a better way to handle it. It's a mix of:

- I don't know what the data type will be

- go SQL driver gives []byte when scanning SQL rows in interface{} (https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/1401)

- I have to use JSON to search in my struct.


Thank you again ! I'll find ways to handle this thanks to you !

Comment: @Gauthier: SQL driver scanning in to byte arrays makes sense. SQL has types like `BLOB`, which is just binary data, so a slice of bytes is the safest fallback type. JSON is, essentially, a test based format, and because the unmarshalling encounters a `"` token, we're not defaulting to string: the format tells us the data is a JSON string.  When you get data from a DB, though, you should know the structure, so create types for that. An over-reliance on `map[string]any` 99.99% of the time is code smell